# how do I expand a ul or div to fill the height of its container

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I am using multiple ULs (column) to provide side-by-side columns at the foot of my page. Each UL sits within a DIV (columnContainer). These DIVs sit within another DIV (shelf) (and then it is turtles all the way up).

I am using the left border of the columnContainer DIV to create a vertical line between each column of content. Because the content in each UL is of different heights, the vertical lines are too.

I want the vertical lines to all be the same size. I think this means that I need my column ULs to expand their height to match the tallest UL, or I need the columnContainer DIVs to expand their height to fill their parent (which is surely controlled in height by the tallest child UL?).

The amount of content and the number of columns varies dynamically so I can't simply define min/max heights.

A sample version of my problem can be found at: http://pastebin.com/ti5u41Ey

any and all help most welcomed

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `height: 100%;` won't work unless there is a height specified on the parent container.

Setting a hard-coded height is not very flexible (you would have to update this value when ever you changed the amount of content in the footer).

A more flexible approach is to use JavaScript. Here's some jQuery that should do the trick:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    recalcColumnHeights ();
    $(window).resize(recalcColumnHeights);
});


recalcColumnHeights = function (){
    tallest = null;
    $('.wptheme-expandedQuickLinksShelfColumnContainer')
        .each(function(){
            if (tallest == null || $(this).height() > tallest.height()) {
                tallest = $(this);
            }
        })
        .height(tallest.height());
    ;
};
</script>
```

Play with an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/m7Z7a/

**EDIT**: Re-sizing the browser window can sometimes affect the height of columns, so you may wish to use this version that recalculates the heights on window resize: http://jsfiddle.net/irama/m7Z7a/1/

Let us know how you go!

Answer (score 1):

a non-javascript solution is using fake backgrounds (in this case one that includes the vertical lines of all the columns).

This will guarantee (visually) that all columns have the *same* height.

example:

**html**:

```
<div class="theBackground">
    (your columns here)
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.theBackground {
    background: url(fakebackground.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

Comment: http://demo.themeshift.com/decanto/contact/ Here is a wordpress theme example. The side column doesn't have any background, but visually it stretches to 100% height.

Comment: @Webars the background on that case is inverted, check it! (the `main-wrap` has the side column background). That's why it *hasn't* a background :)

Comment: The fake background is a good solution if your columns are fixed width and you don't want to do anything fancy (like rounded corners on each column). Based on the CSS from the original post, fake backgrounds would work fine. But the jQuery solution gives you more flexibility.